# Selecting another row based on column value

Tags: mysql

If I have the query below which selects a forum board, but the `board` table contains a column `mirror_board_id`.  Is it possible for me to modify a basic select query to where if `mirror_board_id > 0` that it will `SELECT * FROM board WHERE board_id = mirror_board_id` or something.  Currently I'm using 2 queries to accomplish this, but that's a bit query intensive...

```
SELECT * FROM board WHERE category_id = 7 AND board_id = 0
```

**update**

```
SELECT * FROM board WHERE category_id = 7 AND
                            (
                                    (
                                        mirror_board_id > 0
                                        AND board_id = mirror_board_id
                                    )
                                OR board_id = 0
                            ) AND
                            display = 1 ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

This is returning the wrong boards in the list, it's not actually returning the mirror boards, but original boards where `mirror_board_id > 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logically, it is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM board 
WHERE (mirror_board_id > 0 and board_id = mirror_board_id) 
    or board_id = 0
```

This can be written more succinctly as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM board 
WHERE board_id = coalesce(mirror_board_id, 0)
```

Comment: Could I apply indexing with this to speed it up?  Would indexing `board_id` and `mirror_board_id` separately be enough?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether indexes would help in this case, since you are examining every row. Test and see...

Comment: Ok, I've figured out why.  I need the `category_id` column to be ignored if it's fetching by `coalesce(mirror_board_id, 0)`.  If I'm correct that won't work considering the `category_id` field, at least I can't see a way around it.  Sorry that my original example didn't include `category_id` - I didn't think it would have any effect

Comment: I could use a `case` or `if`, but that seems a bit sloppy and not the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: I think you want: `WHERE board_id = coalesce(mirror_board_id, 0) or category_id = 7`